# Google Colab: Increase TCMALLOC_LARGE_ALLOC_REPORT_THRESHOLD

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a python script which I run on Google Colaboratory using

```
!python3 "/content/gdrive/My Drive/my_folder/my_file.py"
```

And it gives me:

```
tcmalloc: large alloc 21329330176 bytes == 0x18e144000 @  0x7f736dbc2001 0x7f736b6f6b85 0x7f736b759b43 0x7f736b75ba86 0x7f736b7f3868 0x5030d5 0x506859 0x504c28 0x506393 0x634d52 0x634e0a 0x6385c8 0x63915a 0x4a6f10 0x7f736d7bdb97 0x5afa0a
```

And the session crashes. 
Therefore I increase `TCMALLOC_LARGE_ALLOC_REPORT_THRESHOLD` size and run the code by:

```
!TCMALLOC_LARGE_ALLOC_REPORT_THRESHOLD=21329330176 
!python3 "/content/gdrive/My Drive/my_folder/my_file.py"
```

But I still get the same error/warning. What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That warning indicates an attempted allocation of 21329330176 bytes, which is > 20 gigabytes of RAM.

That exceeds the memory capacity of Colab backends, so the crash is expected.

You'll want to restructure your computation to use less concurrent memory, or use a [local runtime](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) in order to make use of backends with more available memory.

Comment: there's one more thing that's annoying me. After yesterday's crash I am unable to connect to drive on colab. I am using:
`from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`, it asks me the authorization code and then runs infinitely. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: Please ask a distinct question for distinct issues.